# read from file line by line, write random lines to another file in C

Tags: c

So i have a file with multiple lines on it, and I want to copy some of those line to a new file, random lines to be specific.
Everything goes fine as long as I copy all the lines file from file, but when I try to introduce randoming, in the new file the lines misses couple characters

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>



int main()
{
    srandom(time(NULL));
    int n,i=0,j=0,k,l;
    char c[200][200];

    char *buff=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char));

    int f= open("erzekelokbeugro.txt",O_RDONLY);
    int f2= open("teszt.txt",O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC,S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IROTH);

    do
    {
        do
        {
            n=read(f,buff,1);
            c[j][i]=*buff;
            //printf("%c",buff[0]);
            i++;
        }
        while(buff[0] !='\n');
        j++;
    }
    while(n>0);

        k=10;
        //j=73;
        i=0;

    while(k>0)
    {   
        j=rand()%49;
            //printf("%d ", j);
        do
        {

            *buff=c[j][i];
            if(buff[0]!=0)
            {
            write(f2,buff,1);

            //printf("%c",buff[0]);
            }

            i++;
        }
        while(buff[0] !='\n');
        //printf("----\n");
        k--;
    }





    close(f);
    close(f2);
    return 0;
}
```

The input is someting like this (i wont copy the whole file, just a sample, its in hungarian, but the content doesnt matter anyway):

```
8.Érzékelés alsó határa (detektálási küszöb)
9.Felbontás
10.Nullponteltolódás (drifft)
11.Érzékenység eltolódás
12.Ismétlési (reprodukciós) hiba
13.Csereszabatosság mértéke
14.Szelektivitás
15.Beállási idő
16.Élettartam
17.Hőmérséklet definíciója
18.Mit tud a Celsius skáláról:
19.Ismertesse a hőmérsékleti együttható (?) képletét az ellenállás-hőmérő esetén.Nevezze meg a képlet elemeit.
```

and the output is like this:

```
és voltmérő sematikus ábrája
5.Linearitás
as műszerek működési elve:
15.Beállási idő
26.Ismertesse a nyomás definícióját, és kiszámítási képletét.
28.Villamos elvű passzív nyomásmérő főbb típusai
34.Ellenállás nyomásérzékelő mérési tartománya és pontossága
29.A villamos elvű nyomásmérők előnyei
35.Piezoelektromos nyomásérzékelés mérési elve
ust használó szenzorok előnyei:
```

As you can see,  all the line should start with a number, but sometimes its missing, also some character (even half a line), but the next goes fine

Comment: this is a very odd thing to do - char *buff=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)); dynamically alloocate space for one character, why not just 'char buff'

Comment: this line:        k--; needs to be immediately followed by: i = 0;  otherwise, the source character could be anywhere.

Comment: why squeeze null bytes out of the output?

Comment: the code needs to check that a line offset is <= 199.  and the number of lines needs to be checked that the count of lines is <= 199.  and why limit the possible line to output to be line 0 through line 48?  And to avoid outputing entries in the array that have not received a line, the array should be initialized to '\0' before any read operations.

Comment: If you opened using fopen() then you could read a line at a time using fgets().  This would greatly speed up the reading operations

Answer (score 1):

`i` needs to be initialized each time you pick a new `j`.  You might also want to look into how to print a whole string at once, instead of doing it a character at a time.